# INSERT INTO SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, select-case

I have two tables, `Variables` and `Processes`.
I want to implement a `INSERT INTO SELECT CASE`, but I've never done this before.

Data goes from `Variables` to `Processes` always.
But I don't know what columns.

For example :

`Variables` table has the columns below :

`Variable_ID`
**`Set_To_Value_ID`**
**`Set_To_Variable_ID`**
**`Changed_In_SP`**
**`Comment_Input`**

The first column is always copied to the `Processes` table. 
`Set_To_Value_ID`, `Set_To_Variable_ID`, `Changed_In_SP`, `Comment_Input` need a `SELECT CASE` because only one can have a value. three of these columns in a row will always be null. Whatever column is not null should be inserted in the `Processes` table :

`Processes` table :

`Process_ID`
`Variable_ID`
**`Value_ID`** - ( `Set_To_Value_ID` goes here )
**`Manual_Value`** - ( `Set_To_Variable_ID`, `Changed_In_SP` *OR* `Comment_Input` goes here )

`Variable_ID_To_Change` goes to `Variable_ID`.

How to proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Value_ID - ( Set_To_Value_ID goes here ) Manual_Value
>
> Set_To_Variable_ID, Changed_In_SP OR Comment_Input goes here )

You can use the [**`COALESCE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) expression like so:

```
INSERT INTO Processes 
SELECT 
  Set_To_Value_ID,
  COALESCE(Set_To_Variable_ID, Changed_In_SP, Comment_Input)
FROM Variables
```

**Update:** Well, since you couldn't use the `COALESCE` for this, here is the canonical way to do that using the `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO Processes
SELECT
   Set_To_Value_ID,
   CASE 
     WHEN Set_To_Variable_ID IS NOT NULL THEN Set_To_Variable_ID 
     WHEN Changed_In_SP IS NOT NULL THEN  Changed_In_SP
     WHEN Comment_Input IS NOT NULL THEN  Comment_Input 
   END
FROM Variables
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use COALESCE though. The reason is that depending on the column selected, some other value ( from a totally different table ) might go into the Manual_Value field. I wanted to implement the SELECT CASE method so I can explicitly decide what goes in the field.